# Angular Jasmin ObjectSpy is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, mocking

I'm trying to spy on service whenever it's called on any test, so a create a mock:

```
import { SpyObject } from './spyobject';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class MockTranslateService extends SpyObject {

  constructor() {
    super(TranslateService);
    this.spy('instant').andReturn('');
  }
}
```

I provide it like this:

```
    {
      provide: TranslateService,
      useValue: MockTranslateService,
    },
```

My component uses `this.translateService.instant` and gets: `TypeError: this.translateService.instant is not a function`.

On the other hand, when I log translateService in my component I get:

```
class MockTranslateService extends spyobject_1.SpyObject {
          constructor() {
              super(core_1.TranslateService);
              this.spy('instant').andReturn(this);
          }
      }
```

any idea why the spy is not working? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way I provided the mock in the test config, it should have been like this:

```
    {
      provide: TranslateService,
      useValue: new MockTranslateService(),
    },
```

Edit:

if you want to use the class name: instead of `useValue` use `useClass`

Answer (score 0):

In order for `this.spy('instant')` to work, you need a function to spy on. This will work:

```
export class MockTranslateService extends SpyObject {
  constructor() {
    super(TranslateService);
    this.spy('instant').andReturn('');
  }

  public instant() { }
}
```

Since the `instant` function is already defined, the spy can be added.

---

**EDIT** This might be easier. In a `beforeEach` block, do the following:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  spyOn(TranslateService.prototype, 'instant');
});
```

This places the spy directly on the prototype and it gets cleaned up after each test.

Comment: It doesn't work, did you test it? also, what's the point of passing the `super(TranslateService);` is I need to redefine all the methods I want to spy one manually

Comment: I was just following the pattern you showed and showing a potential way to fix it. But, there is a simpler solution that should work. I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: I undid the down vote so you don't get penalized, thanks for trying to help, but please test the code next time :)

Comment: It's hard to test the code if you don't give me something to test with.